# Laravel 5.6 Bootstrap Jumbotron Background Image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, background-image

I want to add a background image to my Bootstrap jumbotron. However, I cannot seem to get it right. When I click on the img file in the img folder, I can see that it has been successfully copied over. But I cannot see it when I run http://webdevpro.test:8080/public/img/bootstrap_image.jpg. I get a 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.' Laravel message.

Here is my file structure in my IDE:

[image]

Here is my custom.css file:

```
.jumbotron {

    background-image: url("/public/img/bootstrap_image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Here is the relevant portion of my master file:

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}">

<title>Example Title</title>
```

@include('partials.navbar')

```
<div class="jumbotron">

</div>
```

Please advise where I go wrong.

Comment: Try to not refer to public, instead use `background-image: url("img/bootstrap_image.jpg");`

Comment: if you do: `http://webdevpro.test:8080/img/bootstrap_image.jpg` can you see the img ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your assets in `webdevpro/public` folder, and to access them from your views you can use `asset()` helper method.

Ex. you can retrieve `assets/images/image.png` in your view as following:

```
url("img/bootstrap_image.jpg");
```

Comment: All my assets are in the root public folder. So are you suggesting adding the following as a link? <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/custom.css')}}"> If so, I already have that in my header

Comment: if you do:  `http://webdevpro.test:8080/img/bootstrap_image.jpg`can you see the img ?

Comment: Correct, I can see the image

Comment: Maybe your div is so small the image dont have space to show up, try to put inside of the div a bunch of `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include `public` your URL because it is the only "root" folder exposed by Laravel in a default configuration.

Try this:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("img/bootstrap_image.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you dont need `/` before `img`  anymore

Comment: You're right! Thank you for your input. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried url("img/bootstrap_image.jpg") but the phpstorm gives me a 'Cannot resolve file 'bootstrap_image.jpg' message. The url is also then underlined in red. So that unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So after much searching I gathered that my path to my image was not in the format that phpstorm recognizes. It should look like this...

```
.jumbotron {
background-image: url("../img/thought.jpg");
background-size: cover;
}
```

The ../ should precede the img folder.